# How do I get the format of my URLs to be username/controller/:id in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

I want it similar to the way Twitter handles the URLs for its tweets.

For instance, right now my URL looks like this: `mydomain.com/feedbacks/1/`, where `feedbacks` is the name of the controller.

I want it to look like: `mydomain.com/username/feedbacks/1/` which is similar to Twitter's: `twitter.com/username/status/:id/`.

My `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
  resources :users do
      resources :feedbacks
  end
```

When I have it like this, it gives me the URLs as `mydomain.com/users/1/feedbacks`, but I want the actual username in the URL.

How do I get that?

Thanks.

Edit 1: If you are adding another answer to this question, please make sure it addresses my comments/questions to the answer already given. Otherwise it will be redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scope ":username" do
  resources :feedbacks
end
```

From the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers):

> This will provide you with URLs such as /bob/posts/1 and will allow
>   you to reference the username part of the path as params[:username] in
>   controllers, helpers and views.

---

UPDATE:

I have tested and confirmed the accuracy of paozac's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297231/how-do-i-get-the-format-of-my-urls-to-be-username-controller-id-in-rails-3-1/7350998#7350998). I'll clarify it a bit.

Suppose you had a `@feedback` object with an `id` of `12`, and the associated user had a `username` of `foouser`. If you wanted to generate a URL to the edit page for that `@feedback` object, you could do the following:

```
edit_feedback_url(:username => @feedback.user.username, :id => @feedback)
```

The output would be `"/foouser/feedbacks/12/edit"`.

```
# A URL to the show action could be generated like so:
feedback_url(:username => feedback.user.username, :id => feedback)
#=> "/foouser/feedbacks/12"
# New
new_feedback_url(:username => current_user.username)
#=> "/foouser/feedbacks/new"
```

Additionally, as noted by nathanvda in the comments, you can [pass ordered arguments](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L181) which will be matched with the corresponding dynamic segment. In this case, the username must be passed first, and the feedback id should be passed second, i.e.:

```
edit_feedback_url(@feedback.user.username, @feedback)
```

Also, if you need help handling the params from the controller, I suggest creating a new question specific to that.

Comment: It works, but last thing is, how do I then link to it? I tried `feedbacks_path(feedback)` and it produced the regular `domain.com/:id/feedbacks` URL. Also, on an index page where I have the path, if I have `edit_feedback_path(feedback)` it gives me this routing error: `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"feedbacks",`, but if I pluralize the `edit_feedbackS_path`, I get this error `undefined method 'edit_feedbacks_path' for`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run 'rake routes' from the command line to get all of the routes for your app.

Comment: Here is the `rake routes` output: https://gist.github.com/1193147. If the named routes (i.e. `edit_feedback_path`, etc.) don't have a way to handle route prefixes, you can always write them yourself: `"#{@user.username}/feedbacks/new` or extract this into helper methods that take the user or username as input.

Comment: I did run `rake routes` and tried the paths that I listed above. These are my routes - https://gist.github.com/1193719 but even then when I do `edit_feedback_path(feedback)` it still gives me that routing error. Why would that be? I would think that if it is in my routing table, I wouldn't need to write anything custom, no?

Comment: I even tried this: `<%= link_to 'Edit', :action => :edit, :controller => :feedbacks %>` for this route: `edit_feedback GET    /:username/feedbacks/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"feedbacks"}` and I get this error: `Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"feedbacks"}`.

Comment: Funnily enough, when I go directly to `domain.com/username/feedbacks/:id` it works. So it's just named routes are not being created properly by Rails. Not too familiar with writing my own route prefixes - can you point me to an article/tutorial or some other helpful link that will help get me on my way? Thanks. Edit: I just retried with any string in the URL, not just valid `usernames` and it worked. So it seems as if it's not checking for valid usernames.

Comment: i.e. `domain.com/non-user/feedbacks/2` works, even though `non-user` is not a valid username.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not that familiar with this feature of Rails. I can tell you that in a path like, `/someusername/posts`, your params hash will have a `:username` key, where `params[:username]=="someusername"`. So to get the posts for `someusername` you might try `@posts = User.find_by_username(params[:username]).posts`

Comment: I didn't find anything useful about named routes, i.e. `edit_feedback_path`, being used with a scope. It is simple to create these methods yourself however. `def scoped_edit_feedback_path(user, feedback) "/#{user.username}/#{edit_feedback_path(feedback)}"; end`. I'm totally winging that method but I would do something like that.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Hopefully someone can give me a more elegant solution - if not, then I will try what you have suggested.

Comment: Looks like paozac has the rest of the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297231/how-do-i-get-the-format-of-my-urls-to-be-username-controller-id-in-rails-3-1/7350998#7350998

Comment: nathanvda thanks for that! Makes sense that ordered arguments are associated with corresponding dynamic segments. And the `_url` or `_path` are optional (defaults to `_url`). https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L181

Comment: What would the delete action look like? Before I had this: `<%= link_to 'Delete', feedback, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>` But that is now giving me this error: `(No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"feedbacks", :username=>#<Feedback id: 1, poster_id: 1, receiver_id: 2, content: "Test 2 is awesome", created_at: "2011-09-10 23:00:32", updated_at: "2011-09-10 23:00:32">})`

Comment: Same as show but with different verb, see [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions): `<%= link_to 'Delete', feedback_url(:username => feedback.user.username), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>`

Comment: Sorry, should be `feedback_url(:username => feedback.user.username, :id => feedback)`

Comment: Ok another issue has come up. When I do `/test/feedbacks/3/` for example, it shows me the right feedback, i.e. `feedback` with `:id => 3`, which happens to belong to `user = test`. However, when I do `test2/feedbacks/3/` it still shows me the feedback with `id=3`, but it shouldn't...because that feedback belongs to `username = test`. How do I restrict this from happening?

Comment: You can scope the find through the user, i.e. `User.find_by_username(params[:username]).feedbacks.find(3)`. Or in a `before_filter` you could find the user, i.e. https://gist.github.com/1216898.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to implement something like `Devise` and see if using `current_user` will fix this problem. Thanks for the tip and the gist though. I have forked it, so you can delete if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have defined the scope like dwhalen says you can generate the url like this:

```
feedbacks_url(:username => 'foo')
```

and get

```
http://www.example.com/foo/feedbacks
```

or

```
edit_feedback_url(:username => 'foo', :id => 1)
```

and get

```
http://www.example.com/foo/feedbacks/1/edit
```

Comment: What would the delete action look like? Before I had this: `<%= link_to 'Delete', feedback, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>` But that is now giving me this error: `(No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"feedbacks", :username=>#<Feedback id: 1, poster_id: 1, receiver_id: 2, content: "Test 2 is awesome", created_at: "2011-09-10 23:00:32", updated_at: "2011-09-10 23:00:32">})`

Comment: you can use `feedback_url(:username => 'foo' :id => feedback.id), :method => :delete`